# Use image alt for Fancybox captions

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox

I am trying to use the `title` or 'alt' attribute of images to come up as titles with FancyBox. Here is the relevant code:

```
$("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
        'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
            return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Look ' +
                          (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + 
                           (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
        },
        'autoScale':false,
        'mouseWheelNavigation':   false, 
        'onComplete' : function() {$("#fancybox-wrap").unbind('mousewheel.fb');} ,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are using fancybox v1.3.4,  aren't you?.

To learn how fancybox's titles work in that version [check this post](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/7f2777fca8335aa4/).

To set the fancybox title from the `alt` attribute of your thumbnail, use the API option `titleFromAlt`. You can learn how to use it from [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/3da14d88af2393cc/)

Comment: Thank you very much. The second link instructions work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have made something like this (ver:1.3.4)

```
 $("#modal_informations a[rel='fancy']").fancybox({
        'titleFormat': function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {

            if ($(currentArray[currentIndex]).find('img').length > 0)
            {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-inside">' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + $(currentArray[currentIndex]).find('img').attr('alt') + '</span>';
            }

            return '<span id="fancybox-title-inside">' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + '</span>';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    'titlePosition':'inside',
    'titleFormat': fancyTitle
});
```

// get img alt inside of the fancybox a and overwrite the a title with the img alt inside (dom stays the same, only visible text in the fancybox get changed)

```
function fancyTitle(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts){
        // get current href of a (target image)
        var currHref = jQuery(currentArray[currentIndex]).attr('href');
        // select a by target img url
        return jQuery('a[href="'+currHref+'"]').find('img').attr('alt');
    }
```