# Display ALT text as title within fancybox using jquery.fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, nextgen-gallery

Image HTML looks like this

```
<img  src="image.png" alt="Alt text" title="Description">
```

I have special function to output display Image title as filename with no extension and Description within fancybox.

**My question is: how to get value from alt attribute and output it instead of filename(title_new) if alt is not empty.**

jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js (full http://pastebin.com/bFmg95AT)

```
_format_title = function(title) {
            var nstr=imgPreloader.src;
            var nres=nstr.split("/");

            var img_name=nres[nres.length-1];
            var img_name_arr=img_name.split(".");
            var title_new= "<b>"+img_name_arr[0]+"</b><br>";

        if (title && title.length) {

                if (currentOpts.titlePosition == 'float') {
                    return '<table id="fancybox-title-float-wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td id="fancybox-title-float-left"></td><td id="fancybox-title-float-main">' +title_new+  title+ '</td><td id="fancybox-title-float-right"></td></tr></table>';
                }

                return '<div id="fancybox-title-' + currentOpts.titlePosition + '">' + title_new + title + '</div>';

            }
```

Comment: are you calling fancybox via link and the `<img>` tag is inside that link?

Comment: tag is inside the link, shorten example here:

<a rel="28008" class="ngg-fancybox fancybox image" data-description=" " data-title="025selectaparati-76025" data-image-id="3095" data-thumbnail=[.]025selectaparati-76025.jpg" title=" " href="[.]/025selectaparati-76025.jpg">        <img src="[.]/image.jpg" alt="025selectaparati-76025" title="025selectaparati-76025"></a>

Comment: Since you are using fancybox v1.3.4, that version has an (non-documented) API option `titleFromAlt` that you could use. Check this post I wrote back in 2010 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/PaFNiK8jk8w

Comment: I also replied a similar question in 2012 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9982524/1055987 where I actually make reference to the link above. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To get the alt attribute of an image you would use code like this where 'this' is the image you are using.

```
var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
```

Comment: After using this it says undefined in place '+alt+' was placed. Or do i need to modify it by replacing this to some other code? I see this title = selectedOpts.title || (obj.nodeName ? $(obj).attr('title') : obj.title) || ''; and  title = selectedOpts.orig.attr('alt'); somewhere in the code

Answer (score 0):

This answer works on the basis that 'title_new' has already been declared and given a default value

```
if (typeof $('img').attr('alt') !== typeof undefined && $('img').attr('alt') !== false)
{
    title_new = $('img').attr('alt');
}
```

Comment: doesnt work maybe wrong syntax? This is how it gets title title = selectedOpts.title || (obj.nodeName ? $(obj).attr('title') : obj.title) || '';

Comment: Sorry Rokas. I did check the syntax before posting it up. I wonder over 2 things:
The position which the code is placed in the function.
Have I understood correctly that you wanted to set the value of the title_new variable.